# c++: Boost 1.48 type traits and Cocoa inclusion weirdness

Tags: c++, cocoa, boost

I just updated boost to version 1.48.0 on a project i am developing on OSX Lion that also includes the Cocoa headers. After doing so I got a load of errors all pointing to has_prefix_operator.hpp and has_binary_operator.hpp which all point to lines like i.e.:

```
   BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = (sizeof(check(((make<Lhs>() BOOST_TT_TRAIT_OP make<Rhs>()),make<has_operator>())))==sizeof(::boost::type_traits::yes_type)));
```

> ../../boost_1_48_0/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp:157:4:
>   error: expected expression [1]

After trying around, since I could not really read any sense into these errors, I noticed that if I switch the inclusion order from:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
```

to

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

things magically work. I am very confused about that since it worked just fine with the previous boost release and I have no clue why this is happening. Any ideas about what might be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems `Cocoa.h` is directly or indirectly defining a macro with the same name as one of the identifiers used in the Boost code.

Comment: hmm yeah that is most likely it.- Seems weird though since all boost macros start with BOOST_ and are thus rather unique. ty!

Comment: I don't mean to say that `Cocoa.h` is defining a macro beginning with `BOOST_`; I mean to say that `Cocoa.h` is defining a macro named `Lhs` or `Rhs` or `has_operator` or somesuch other terrible macro name, and that it's conflicting with the proper identifiers in use in the Boost code.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.- Hope that will be fixed in the next release because this is somewhat of an annoyance.

Comment: The header causes a similar bug in combination with Qt. So you might want to look for something related in the bug tracker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had essentially the same problem, and with the clue from ildjam, I found the cause and a work-around.

The (terrible) macro name is check, defined in AssertMacros.h. According to the comments in that file, in the future Apple will remove the old names. For now Apple have added a work-around to suppress the old names which is to define __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES to 0 before AssertMacros.h is processed. e.g.

```
#define __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES 0
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

If you use a prefix file, then you could put the definition there. Alternatively, a direct work-around is to undef check before including type_traits.hpp.

```
#ifdef check
#undef check
#endif
#include "boost/type_traits.hpp"
```

(Details submitted to Boost Trac too: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6219 )

Comment: Using boost 1.55 on OS X 10.9.2 and this answer is still relevant and correct. It seems that this has been fixed in type_traits as of 3 weeks ago. See the bug report listed above for more info.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Reposting from comments since this apparently is the answer...</sup>

It seems `Cocoa.h` is directly or indirectly defining a macro with the same name as one of the identifiers used in the Boost code. I.e., `Cocoa.h` is defining a macro named `Lhs` or `Rhs` or `has_operator` or some other equally terrible macro name, and it's conflicting with the proper identifiers in use in the Boost code.

If you'd like to contribute to getting this fixed in a future version of Boost, please narrow down the offending macro name(s) and submit a bug report on [Boost Trac](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/).