# Generating project with PCL (Point Cloud Library) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, linker, cmake

I installed all the dependencies and the pre-compiled PCL library as it suggested on their [site](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/macosx.html).

After I installed everything I wanted to generate a project following [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php#using-pcl-pcl-config) tutorial.

After executing the 'make' command I get several warnings and the following two errors:

```
37 warnings generated.
Linking CXX executable pcd_write_test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "pcl::PCDWriter::writeASCII(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 const&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1> const&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0> const&, int)", referenced from:
      pcl::PCDWriter::write(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 const&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1> const&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0> const&, bool) in pcd_write.cpp.o
  "pcl::PCDWriter::writeBinary(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 const&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1> const&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0> const&)", referenced from:
      pcl::PCDWriter::write(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 const&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1> const&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0> const&, bool) in pcd_write.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [pcd_write_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd_write_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Anybody has any suggestions how to fix this?

I am using Mac OS X 10.9.4.

Comment: I found the solution in this [thread][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318961/how-do-i-link-pcl-library-properly-for-use-within-an-objective-c-app-compiled-in

Comment: Did you find the solution in the end? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes, I found the solution in the above link (first comment).

Comment: I looked at that, but changing the C++ language dialect and/or the C++ standard library didn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 3):

on a mac-book pro yosemite(10.10.3) i have done the following
to get the pcl-tutorial (pcd_write.cpp) running.

in the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MY_GRAND_PROJECT)
find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable(pcd_write_test pcd_write.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pcd_write_test ${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES})
```

running ccmake .. in build-directory gives

```
 CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE                                                              
 CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX             /usr/local                                   
 CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES                                                       
 CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET                                                   
 CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT                                                             
 DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR             DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND                
 DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY                 DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND                    
 EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS               /opt/local/include/eigen3                    
 ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR              ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND                 
 ENSENSO_LIBRARY                  ENSENSO_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND                     
 LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR             /opt/local/include                           
 LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY                 /opt/local/lib/libusb-1.0.dylib              
 OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIRS             OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIRS-NOTFOUND                
 OPENNI2_LIBRARY                  OPENNI2_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND                     
 OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIRS              /usr/include/ni                              
 OPENNI_LIBRARY                   /usr/lib/libOpenNI.dylib                     
 PCL_COMMON_INCLUDE_DIR           /usr/local/include/pcl-1.8 
 PCL_DIR                          /usr/local/share/pcl-1.8                     
 PCL_IO_INCLUDE_DIR               /usr/local/include/pcl-1.8                   
 PCL_OCTREE_INCLUDE_DIR           /usr/local/include/pcl-1.8
```

and the code i compiled succesfully

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //insert code here..
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;

    cloud.width    = 5;
    cloud.height   = 1;
    cloud.is_dense = false;
    cloud.points.resize (cloud.width * cloud.height);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud.points.size (); ++i){
        cloud.points[i].x = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        cloud.points[i].y = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        cloud.points[i].z = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    }

    pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII ("test_pcd.pcd", cloud);
    std::cerr << "Saved " << cloud.points.size () << " data points to test_pcd.pcd." << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud.points.size (); ++i)
        std::cerr << "    " << cloud.points[i].x << " " << cloud.points[i].y << " " << cloud.points[i].z << std::endl;

    return (0);

    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

...hope its usefull for someone!

nik

Comment: Thank you! Binding cmake directly to the pcl-1.8 library worked for me! after all the cruft I had pcl-1.6 and pcl-1.8... for OSX the thing that worked was installing with brew and that got 1.8 working and running (I think, but not sure)... using 1.8 I got :./pcd_write_test
Saved 5 data points to test_pcd.pcd.
    0.0080142 0.694695 -0.26015
    -0.342265 -0.446349 0.214207
    0.173687 -0.84253 -0.400481
    -0.874475 0.706127 -0.117635
    0.908514 -0.598159 0.744714