# PCL 1.8 on MAC OS errors in CMake generated Makefile

Tags: macos, cmake, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to get PCL 1.8 (The point cloud library) working on Mac OS 10.9.5, I installed all the dependencies and pcl using brew. My brew list indicates:

```
$ brew list
autoconf        libebml         pcl
automake        libmatroska     pcre
boost           libogg          pkg-config
cmake           libpng          qhull
cminpack        libtiff         qt
eigen           libtool         readline
expat           libusb          scons
flann           libvorbis       sip
fontconfig      makedepend      sqlite
freetype        mkvtoolnix      subversion
gettext         openni                  szip
glew            openni2                 vtk
hdf5            openni2-freenectdriver  wxmac
jpeg            openssl                 xz
```

My cpp and CMakeLists.txt are the [same at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168269/generating-project-with-pcl-point-cloud-library-on-mac-os-x.). After executing the 'cmake ..' command I get several warnings indicating an inclomplete configuration

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- checking for module 'eigen3'
--   found eigen3, version 3.2.10
-- Found eigen: /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.10/include/eigen3  
-- Boost version: 1.62.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   date_time
--   iostreams
--   serialization
-- checking for module 'libopenni'
--   found libopenni, version 1.5.7.10
-- Found openni: /usr/local/Cellar/openni/1.5.7.10/lib/libOpenNI.dylib  
-- checking for module 'libopenni2'
--   package 'libopenni2' not found
-- Found OpenNI2: /usr/local/lib/ni2/libOpenNI2.dylib  
-- Could NOT find ensenso (missing:  ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to ensenso will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing:  DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to davidSDK will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DSSDK (missing:  _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** io features related to dssdk will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-7.0/VTKTargets.cmake:1361 (message):
  This file relies on consumers using CMake 2.8.12 or greater.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-7.0/VTKConfig.cmake:68 (include)
  /Applications/CMake 2.8-11.app/Contents/share/cmake-     2.8/Modules/FindVTK.cmake:73 (find_package)
  /usr/local/share/pcl-1.8/PCLConfig.cmake:501 (find_package)
  /usr/local/share/pcl-1.8/PCLConfig.cmake:659 (find_VTK)
  /usr/local/share/pcl-1.8/PCLConfig.cmake:849 (find_external_library)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Im probably doing something dumb, but I'm stumped. Ideas are welcome.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You get **single error** with message `This file relies on consumers using CMake 2.8.12 or greater.` It means that you cmake is too old for use VTK. Try to update cmake.

Comment: I replaced the cmake by a new version and it works. Thanks..